# get all occurences from a string based on find pattern in python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Suppose I have a string like this:

```
exp = 'CASE WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'CPU\'  THEN   \'YES\'  WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'RAM\'  THEN   \'YES\' ELSE  \'NO\' END'
```

```
exp2 = 'CASE WHEN  ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"*"Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")>0  THEN  ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"* "Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE") ELSE ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"+ "Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")   END '
```

I want to return the all occurrences of WHEN and THEN along with the texts of that.

This is the expected output of exp1

```
['WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'CPU\'  THEN   \'YES\'','WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'RAM\'  THEN   \'YES\'']
```

This is the expected output of exp2

```
['WHEN  ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"*"Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")>0  THEN  ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"* "Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")']
```

What I have tried is this:

```
res = re.findall(r'\s*(WHEN|When|when)+\s*(.*)\s*(THEN|Then|then)+\s*')
```

But the resulting list shows this output in my case

```
['(WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'CPU\'  THEN   \'YES\'  WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'RAM\'  THEN)']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
WHEN (?:(?! +(?:WHEN|ELSE)).)* # with flags=re.I
```

1. `WHEN`  - Matches 'WHEN '
2. `(?:(?! +(?:WHEN|ELSE)).)` - Uses negative lookahead and states that as long as the current position does not match one or more space characters followed by either 'WHEN' or 'ELSE', then match one more character.

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/460tlk/1/)

```py
import re

cases = [
    'CASE WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'CPU\'  THEN   \'YES\'  WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'RAM\'  THEN   \'YES\' ELSE  \'NO\' END',
    'CASE WHEN  ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"*"Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")>0  THEN  ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"* "Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE") ELSE ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"+ "Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")   END '
]

for case in cases:
    res = re.findall(r'WHEN (?:(?! +(?:WHEN|ELSE)).)*', case, flags=re.I)
    print(res)
```

Prints:

```
['WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'CPU\'  THEN   \'YES\'', 'WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'RAM\'  THEN   \'YES\'']
['WHEN  ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"*"Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")>0  THEN  ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"* "Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")']
```

**Update**

If you want to group the WHEN and ELSE parts (stripped of leading and trailing spaces), then use the following regex:

```
WHEN +(.*?) +THEN +((?:(?! +(?:WHEN|ELSE)).)*)
```

```py
import re

cases = [
    'CASE WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'CPU\'  THEN   \'YES\'  WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'RAM\'  THEN   \'YES\' ELSE  \'NO\' END',
    'CASE WHEN  ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"*"Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")>0  THEN  ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"* "Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE") ELSE ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"+ "Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")   END '
]

for case in cases:
    results = re.findall(r'WHEN +(.*?) +THEN +((?:(?! +(?:WHEN|ELSE)).)*)', case, flags=re.I)
    for result in results:
        print(result[0], result[1])
```

Prints:

```
"Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"='CPU' 'YES'
"Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"='RAM' 'YES'
("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"*"Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")>0 ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"* "Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")
```

Comment: Hye.. `CASE WHEN  ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"*"Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")>0  THEN  ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"* "Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE") ELSE ("Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"+ "Expressions"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")   END 
` In this case it doesnot work since we can have whitespace characters after **THEN**.Please resolve this

Comment: I am not quite following. Update your question with new input and expected output **and** you need to specify clearly a rule that states when to stop scanning. Before one could infer that the rule was after seeing THEN followed by whitespace you then scan the next set of non-whitespace characters and then stop. For example, stop when you see the next occurrence of WHEN or the end of string.

Comment: updated my question and required output for exp2..The scenario is after the THEN keyword there can be whitespace characters also in between.Since we specified \S+,this testcase fails.

Comment: I think we should stop scanning when **when** or **else**  keyword occurs.how can we do that

Comment: I have to go out for a short while, but I will look at this when I return.

Comment: How can i group the contents in this regex..for ex want to get contents between WHEN and THEN ..and content after THEN in the list result

Comment: Is there no end to this? You can't post multipart questions that go on ad infinitum. Accept this answer or not and then post a new question. It's not even clear what your new question means since what ends the match could be WHEN and not THEN. And if you want the THEN part for when it is WHEN ... THEN ..., a whole different approach would be used. So your best best, now that what your looking for seems to be quite different than your original question, is to post a new question that is clear.

Comment: Sorry for this but in the previous regular expression u posted i could group the parts as `when( .*?) then\s+(\S+)` to get required contents from the string..Hence asked if we could do the same with updated regex